# PHP four levels of quotes

Tags: php, quote

Is there any possible way to have four levels of quotes? Or a more efficient way to print javascript using PHP?

Here is the context for why I need four levels of quotes:

The first level is required to wrap around script to echo.

```
<?php echo '<script></script>';
```

The second level is required to wrap around html to print in java

```
<?php echo '<script>document.getElementByid("box").innerHTML = \'<button>test</button>\'</script>';
```

The third level is to wrap around onclick function in button

```
<?php echo '<script>document.getElementByid("box").innerHTML = \'<button onclick="some_function()">test</button>\'</script>';
```

The fourth level is to wrap around the parameters in the function

```
<?php echo '<script>document.getElementByid("box").innerHTML = \'<button onclick="some_function(*insert quote*parameter*insert quote*)">test</button>\'</script>';
```

Edit 1:
The entire script needs to be in echoed by php because in some scenarios the entire scripts needs to exist and other scenarios it needs to not exist e.g.

```
<?php if($variable == "do_not_print"){// do nothing}else{//echo script}
```

Comment: Since there are no PHP variables / functions in your `echo` strings, why bother with PHP at all? `?><script>...</script><?php // and now back to PHP`

Comment: is there an underlying reason why you want your script echoed in PHP?

Comment: I think it's better to use **PHP heredoc**  [See how to use](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid string quoting problems by dropping out of the PHP context entirely and using

```
<?= ... ?>
```

to insert server-side values into the output.

`json_encode()` also helps sanitise values for safe use in a JavaScript context.

I also recommend using the DOM library for creating and inserting elements

For example

```php
if ($someThingOrOther) :
// end PHP context
?>
<script>
(() => { // IIFE to avoid polluting the global scope
  const someValueFromPhp = <?= json_encode($someValue) ?>
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  button.textContent = 'test'

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    some_function(someValueFromPhp)
  }, false)

  const box = document.getElementById('box')
  // empty out "box", faster than using "innerHTML"
  while(box.firstChild) {
    box.removeChild(box.firstChild)
  }
  box.appendChild(button)
})()
</script>
<?php
// and now back to PHP
else:
?>
<script>
// ...
</script>
<?php
endif;
```

Comment: It needs to be all php because it's wrapped in an if/else statement

e.g.
<?php if ($variable=="1"){echo script 1}else{echo script 2}?>

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. You can drop in and out of the `<?php ... ?>` context at any time

Comment: In one scenario the script is needed, in another scenario a completely different script is needed and sometimes no script is needed. Which is why it needs to all be in php so I can wrap it in an if/else statement

Comment: @TheodoreLevitt no, it really does not need to be in PHP at all. I've updated my answer to show you

Answer (score 2):

quote 1: `''`
quote 2: `""`
quote 3: `\'\'`
quote 4: `\"\"`

like this:

```
      <div id="root"></div>
      <?php
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "<button onclick=\"alert(\'its work\')\">test</button>\n";
      </script>';
      ?>
```